# (Facebook SDK 4.x) Sharing a link to a friends wall

Tags: facebook

I'm currently updating from Facebook SDK 3.x to 4.x on iOS and Android and can't seem to figure out how to share a link to a friends wall. Previously I used FBWebDialogs that accepted a "to" field in the parameters, but now using the FBSDKShareLinkContent and FBSDKShareDialog there doesn't seem to be any option like this.

I couldn't find any explicit mentioning of fully dropping support for this in 4.x, so would anyone know if this is still possible in some way? Preferably with a dialog and not behind the scenes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code should do the trick..

```
if ([[FBSDKAccessToken currentAccessToken] hasGranted:@"publish_actions"]) {
    [[[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
      initWithGraphPath:@"me/feed"
      parameters: @{ @"message" : @"your messag / link"}
      HTTPMethod:@"POST"]
     startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection, id result, NSError *error) {
         if (!error) {
             NSLog(@"Post id:%@", result[@"id"]);
         }
     }];
}
```